# How to create a List<class> and verify if list contains item already

Tags: c#, list, contains

Easier if I show I am trying to do:

```
public struct Server
{
   public string ServerName;
   public string SiteName;
}

List<Server> targetServerList = GetTargetServerList();
```

targetServerList will have the following data:

```
SiteName: A
ServerName: 1

SiteName: A
ServerName: 2

SiteName: B
ServerName: 3

SiteName: C
ServerName: 4
```

GOAL: I need to create a list that will contain the following:

```
SiteName: Site A
ServerNames: 1,2

SiteName: Site B
ServerNames: 3

SiteName: Site C
ServerNames: 4
```

So I created the following class:

```
private class ServersPerSite
{
   string ServerNames;
   string SiteName;
}
```

So now I need to loop and add a new item with new SiteName if SiteName does not exist yet plus add ServerName into it. If it does exist, I just need to add the ServerName:

```
foreach (Server server in targetServerList)
{
  //??missing code
}
```

How do I do that? in Javascript was really simple:

```
  //Separate the servers per site
  var sites=new Object();

  $("#ServerGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data').forEach(function(row) 
  {
    if(!sites[row.SiteName])
    {
        sites[row.SiteName] = new Array();
    }
    sites[row.SiteName][sites[row.SiteName].length] = row.ServerName;
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case a `Dictionary<string, string>` or even `Dictionary<string, IList<string>>` would be the better choice.

```
public struct Server
{
   public string ID;
   public string SiteName;
}



private IDictionary<string, IList<string>> servers;

foreach(var server in GetTargetServerList()){
    if(!servers.ContainsKey(server.SiteName) {
        servers.Add(server.SiteName, new List<string>());
    }
    servers[server.SiteName].Add(server.ID);
}
```

Comment: not sure what I am doing wrong. I don't have a AddRange method and I am getting the error below:
                servers.Add(server.SiteName, server.ID); 
                //Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>>.Add(string, System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>)'
                //has some invalid arguments

Comment: OK, forgot about that IList doesn't define AddRange-method. I updated the example so that it should work with the code in your comment.

Comment: I had to do a small change because I was getting "Use of unassigned local variable 'servers' ".
So I used Dictionary and had to instanciate it too:

        Dictionary<string, IList<string>> servers = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ with `GroupBy` method:

```
var result = targetServerList
                .GroupBy(s => s.SiteName)
                .Select(g => new ServersPerSite()
                            {
                                SiteName = "Site " + g.Key,
                                ServerNames = string.Join(",", g);
                            });
```

**Edit:** result as `Dictionary`

```
targetServerList.GroupBy(s => s.SiteName)
                .ToDictionary(g => "Site " + g.Key,
                              g => string.Joins(",", g));
```

Comment: I would add a ToDictionary to the end of this so it's compatible with what is being done in JavaScript.

Comment: hmmm I am getting: "Error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type"